# how to display text box value in aui popup in liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-aui

in this jsp i have displayed the popup when i click it on button using aui.. i want to display the text box value when i click it on the popup box can any one help me?.i dont know how to use pop.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>

<div id="a">
    <aui:input lable="enter name" name="name" type="text"></aui:input>
</div>
<div id="b">
    <aui:button name="hello" value="click me" onclick='callPopup()'></aui:button>
</div>

<aui:script >

function callPopup(){

    AUI().ready('aui-dialog', 'aui-overlay-manager', 'dd-constrain', function(A) {
        alert('hai sudheer');
        var dialog = new A.Dialog({

            title: 'DISPLAY CONTENT',

            centered: true,

            modal: true,

            draggable:true,

            width: 300,

            height: 300,

            closeOnOutsideClick: true,

            bodyContent: "This is testing content inside the popup"

        }).render();

    });

}

</aui:script >
```

Comment: what you want? elaborate it

Comment: i have a text box in the form,ok when i clik on the button it shows popup in the same page.now i want to display the text box value on popup.for example if i enter 'sudheer' in text box i have to display the hai sudheer in popup box.in the above code popup is "This is testing content inside the popup"besides it i want to display sudheer

Comment: try `bodyContent: A.node("#hello").val()` where `hello` is the `id="hello"` of `<aui:input />`

Comment: i have added like this:                                    bodyContent: "This is testing content inside the popup"+A.node("#b").val() its not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>
<aui:input lable="enter name" name="name" type="text" id="b"></aui:input>
<div id="a">
<aui:button name="hello" value="click me" onclick='callPopup()'></aui:button>
</div>
<portlet:namespace/>
<aui:script >

function callPopup(){

AUI().ready('aui-dialog', 'aui-overlay-manager', 'dd-constrain', function(A) {
var name = document.getElementById("_popexample_WAR_popupexampleportlet_b").value;
var sudheer="hai"+name;
alert('hai sudheer'+name);
var dialog = new A.Dialog({

title: 'DISPLAY CONTENT',

centered: true,

modal: true,

draggable:true,

width: 300,

height: 300,

bodyContent: sudheer

}).render();

});

}

</aui:script >
```

its working fine....tested...thanks